# S3FS ownership and permissions

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to mount a S3 bucket to my local machine using secret password key with the following command:

s3fs mybucket /mnt/mybucket -o allow_other -o umask=0000,uid=$UID -o use_cache=/tmp -o default_acl=public-read-write

This should give +rwx to all the files/directories under /mnt/mybucket and it does.

However, when I try to do the following:
sudo cp /mnt/mybucket/from/abc.txt /mnt/mybucket/to

I get permission denied even thought both directories are +rwx.

Also, If I try to create a file within from/ or to/ sub-directories, I get the following error:
touch abc.txt
touch: setting times of ‘abc.txt’: No such file or director

Can anyone tell me how I could give non-root user on my local machine the privileges to copy files from "from/" to "to" directories.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of s3fs do you run?  1.85 fixes some of the default permission issues.

Comment: @AndrewGaul Thanks for your reply but I have abandoned this task so unable to provide that info now.

Answer (score 1):

Just for others coming to this... make sure you have                "s3:PutObjectAcl" set on your policy for the relative role your creds are for.